# Ensuring the uniqueness of the solution for an ODE on an infinite domain

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Q. Consider the ODE $$y'=y^2,~y(0)=1,$$I got $y=\frac{1}{1-x}$ as a unique solution on $(-\infty,1)$. But I am not sure about the justification behind the uniqueness over the semi-infinite interval $(-\infty,1)$. Picards theorem provide me the uniqueness in an interval $[-h,h]$ for some $h>0$ since $f(t,y)=y^2$ and $f_{y}=2y$ is continuous on a rectangle $R$ containing the interior point $(0,1)$. Also, $f$ seem to be not Lipschitz on $(-\infty,1)$ since $|f(t,-n)-f(t,0)|=n^2$ cannot be controled by $Ln,~n \in \mathbb N$ for some constant $L>0$. Then how to conclude the above solution is unique on $(-\infty,1)$?

Comment: $f$ is *locally Lipschitz* with respect to $y$, and that is sufficient to guarantee the *uniqueness* of any solution of the initial value problem.

Comment: Sir,  I think  we can say 'locally Lipschitz' suffices to have uniquesness but doesnot suffice to have the global existence, while 'globally Lipschitz' guarentees both, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thank you Sir....

Comment: You can also check uniqueness just by solving the equation directly. This is a separable equation. Since $y(0)=1,$ we can safely assume $y(t)^2\gt0,$ so $y'=y^2$ implies $y^{-2}y'=1=\left(-y^{-1}\right)'=1,$ so by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $$[-y(t)^{-1}]-[-y(0)]^{-1}=y(0)^{-1}-y(t)^{-1}=1-y(t)^{-1}=t,$$ equivalent to $$1-t=y(t)^{-1},$$ equivalent to $$y(t)=(1-t)^{-1}.$$ There were no assumptions used in the derivation not already justified by the problem itself. So this solution is unique.